# Crystal Reports Viewer 2011 crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

We are developing an application which generates reports in .rpt format. When we open the various types of report using Crystal Report Viewer 2011 all of them work fine except for one, which causes Crystal Report Viewer to crash ( - [Internal Error DataViewL573] ).

The application is built with Visual Studio 2005. The reports are generated with the Crystal Decisions plugin.

I have two reports; One that loads fine in the Viewer (GOOD.rpt), and one that causes it to crash (BAD.rpt).

Does anyone know of any quick avenues of investigation outside of taking apart the report construction process itself? Are there any known issues with the viewer that I should be aware of?

Cheers,
Lordmonkey.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380097/changes-dont-get-saved-in-crystal-reports-report/17382876#17382876

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a "corrupted" report. Not all Crystal runtime engines are created equal.

See this KB article:

http://www.jeff-net.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/16/0/my-crystal-report-will-not-run-whats-the-problem